# Sharepoint online w/ external storage?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am administrating sharepoint online and our storage usage is almost at 1.4TB of data. Our files increase at a great rate these days and we are looking at other alternatives since Sharepoint's extra tier of storage is pricey.

Is it possible to integrate sharepoint online to other cloud storage like Remote Blob Storage/ Google drive / Box /etc?

Answer (score 0):

No as it would be up to Microsoft to implement such a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As trevor mentioned, SPO's online storage space is directly managed by Microsoft. You could try to store documents in other tools, online documents do not support storage in other tools.